# nc -l in background closes immediately (nc -l 1234 &)

Tags: tcp, telnet, netcat

When I put this

```
nc -l 12345 >nc_out
```

in a shell script, run it and then connect from other shell using telnet, it allows me to type some text and have it end up in *nc_out*.

But if I start nc in the background (I want to start telnet from the same script later on):

```
nc -l 12345 >nc_out &
```

connection is closed immediately:

```
# telnet localhost 12345
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host
#
```

leaving the nc_out file empty.

Why is that?  How can I make nc accept connection normally?

---

Notes:

- On RHEL and Fedora, both *nc* and *nmap-ncat* behave this way, but
  Debian's *nc-traditional* does accept the connection and let me save
  the data to nc_out.
- It does not matter if I call telnet from the same script or different
  (SSH) session, the behavior is the same
- I also ran the command with strace as @Hauke Laging suggested and posted
  the [strace output on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YZHW31ef)

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with openSUSE. Maybe it helps to run it this way in order to get some hints about the problem: `strace -o nc.strace nc -l 12345 >nc_out &`

Comment: The strange thing about this is that it seems that something immediately connects to the `nc` socket (`accept(3, ...`; but without sending anything). For some reason the connection is closed then. Maybe the timeout. `strace -t` gives time stamps.

Comment: @HaukeLaging [here](http://pastebin.com/YZHW31ef) is the new paste with timestamps.  The 26 second offset is caused by me waiting before calling telnet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backgrounded commands that are executed in non-interactive shells with job control disabled (as it is the case in shell scripts) get their `stdin` implicitly redirected from `/dev/null`.

```
sh -c 'nc -l 12345 1>nc_out & lsof -p $!'
```

From [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02):

> ## 2. Shell Command Language
>
> [...]
>
> ### Asynchronous Lists
>
> If a command is terminated by the control operator  ( '&' ), the
>   shell shall execute the command asynchronously in a subshell. This means
>   that the shell shall not wait for the command to finish before executing
>   the next command.
>
> The format for running a command in the background is:
>
> ```
> command1 & [command2 & ... ]
> ```
>
> The standard input for an asynchronous list, before any explicit
>   redirections are performed, shall be considered to be assigned to a file
>   that has the same properties as **/dev/null**. If it is an interactive
>   shell, this need not happen. In all cases, explicit redirection of standard
>   input shall override this activity.

When the `telnet` client establishes its connection to `localhost` and the already running `nc` command via port `12345`, the backgrounded `nc` command seems to detect EOF on its stdin and starts its shutdown process because it is forced reading from /dev/null. A return value of zero of the `read` command (`man 2 read`) indicates end of file.

```
# strace output (from http://pastebin.com/YZHW31ef)
14:32:26 read(0, "", 2048)              = 0
14:32:26 shutdown(4, 1 /* send */)      = 0
```

Here are some solutions to keep `telnet` running and communicating with `nc`:

```
sh -c 'nc -l 12345 0<&0 1>nc_out &'
sh -c 'nc -l 12345 0<&- 1>nc_out &'
sh -c 'tail -f /dev/null | nc -l 12345 1>nc_out &'
sh -c 'rm -f fifo; mkfifo fifo; exec 3<>fifo; nc -l 12345 0<fifo 1>nc_out &'
```

Comment: Welcome to our community! Nice answer. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

```
nc -ld host port >> logfile &
```

-d      Do not attempt to read from stdin.

This will be executed ‘nc’ in the background.
Beacuse,when background execut 'nc',it's will read stdin stdout stderr.
If reading stdin isn't prohibited,it's will abort.

example:

```
nc -ld 12345 > nc_out

nc 127.0.0.1 12345 
#enter something
```

The data is stored in **nc_out** file.

Comment: Please explain better why this solves the problem in the question. Your command `nc -d host port` doesn't really match the command `nc -l 12345` in the question. I don't really understand the sentence "Runtime will be executed ‘nc’ in the background."

Comment: Sorry, I omitted some descriptions.
Now it's complete.
THK.